# Google Analytics: GANTrackerError 195946409 - reason?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm using the Google Analytics library in my iPhone/iPad app; one part of the code sometimes throws an error, the [error localizedDescription] shows the following:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.googleanalytics.GANTrackerError error 195946409.
```

I didn't find any information about this error code; the app doesn't crash there, but I'm assuming that the tracking also doesn't work in that case. Does someone know the reason?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: the code in question:

```
    [[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:0
                                                    name:@"article"
                                                   value:[model name]
                                               withError:&error];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got it: customVariableAtIndex must not be 0; it seems like it has to start at 1...

Answer (score 0):

It appears this error 195946409 can appear for a number of reasons, not limited to just setting an incorrect index. For example, If your value is too long, you will get the same error.